# Populate a table with Foreign keys in it

Tags: php, mysql

I have a schema like this

```
CREATE TABLE TrainManager(
    train_name    VARCHAR(5) REFERENCES Train(name),
    station_id      INT REFERENCES Station(station_id)
);
```

The two reference tables have an indirect relations.

> control (ctrl_id, train_name);
>
> controlremote (ctrl_id, station_id);

As you can, in order to get `train name` and `station id`, we need to get into the other two tables to compare `ctrl_id` besides comparing the train_name and station_id.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `train` (train_name, station_id)
    SELECT t.train_name, st.station_id
    FROM train, station
    WHERE t.train_name = ( SELECT c.train_name FROM control c
                           WHERE c.train_name = t.train_name)
            AND
          st.station_id = ( SELECT cr.station_id FROM controlremote cr
                            WHERE cr.station_id = st.station_id)
            AND
```

But I can't think of a proper SQL synatx to compare the ctrl_id ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO `train` (train_name, station_id)
SELECT control.train_name, controlremote.station_id
FROM control
LEFT JOIN controlremote ON control.ctrl_id = controlremote.ctrl_id
```

Something along this way. Just join both tables on `ctrl_id`. I hope I understood correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. It's clear now. I am using the same idea throughout in my project. Thanks.